# Listing in item, how to make the list in the same line with the bullet

Tags: beamer, itemize, lstlisting

I am working with `beamer` to make slides. When I try to add some code in `lstlist` inside an item list, the list is always in the next line compared to the bullet, as in the following picture.

[image]

My code is as the following:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usecolortheme{crane}
\useoutertheme{split}
\usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\tiny \ttfamily,
    frame=single,
}

\begin{document}
    \section{listing in item}
        \begin{frame}[t, fragile]{Listing in Item}
            \begin{onlyenv}<+>
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item
                        \begin{lstlisting}[autogobble]
                            How to align this with the bullet? 
                        \end{lstlisting}
                \end{itemize}
            \end{onlyenv}
        \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to raise the list one line above to align to the bullet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick workaround: change the `aboveskip` of your listing

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usecolortheme{crane}
\useoutertheme{split}
\usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\tiny \ttfamily,
    frame=single,
}

\begin{document}
    \section{listing in item}
        \begin{frame}[t, fragile]{Listing in Item}
            \begin{onlyenv}<+>
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item
                        \begin{lstlisting}[autogobble,aboveskip=-.8\baselineskip]
                            How to align this with the bullet? 
                        \end{lstlisting}
                \end{itemize}
            \end{onlyenv}
        \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @samcarter, your answer is always like a bolt:)

Comment: check the definition of `\baselineskip`, one follow up question is, why 0.8, not 1?

Comment: @EricSun I used 0.8 instead of 1 to compensate for your change in font size from normal to tiny. (but the number is just a guess, you could look up the exact difference)

Comment: get it, 0.8 works perfectly in this case.